# Ruby : Regex help on sentences

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I get only the begining of the 2 firsts sentences with a regex (A14/16 & A14/14) but nothing on the last ?

```
A14/16 Working class
A14/14 New oject
Meeting up with boss
```

I thought about theses but it's not right because it does the contrary :s

```
(\s.+)
```

Comment: how is the third sentence different than the first two?

Comment: That's what I got can't say really why, and I want to "strip" all text and keep the begining (A14/16 & A14/14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't tell how one can identify the first two lines, we have to guess - this will work:

```
(^A\S+)
```

This will return the first word of each line beginning with the letter `A`

[demo](http://rubular.com/r/whxT9EPN4b)

Answer (score 1):

This is an option:

```
result = subject.scan(/^[^\s\/]*\/[^\s\/]*/)
```

This matches the part of the string that contains a `/`